# Take a square and divide it into N equally sized smaller squares, and return the coordinates of their centres

Tags: python, algorithm, math

Let's say I have a square, 100 by 100 in dimension.

If I say `N=4`, the centres returned would be `(25,25) (25,75) (75,25) (75,75)`

How do I go about creating an algorithm to work this out? Thanks

Comment: What do you think the first step would be? Any ideas what to do after that? Edit your question to include any thoughts, even if you're not sure about viability or optimization.

Comment: Is N itself always a [square number](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_number), like 4 (which is 2*2) in your example ? Are all the smaller squares of the same size ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `N` is a square number, here's one way:

```
import math
nd = 100.
N = 4
n = int(math.sqrt(N))
d = nd / n
c = [i*d+d/2 for i in range(n)]
[[(x,y) for x in c] for y in c]

=== Output: ===
[[(25, 25), (75, 25)], [(25, 75), (75, 75)]]
```

`d` is the edge-length of each square, there are `n` along each side of the large square to be tiled; their centres are displaced from their edges by `d/2`.